# Library projects in Eclipse missing after Github clone?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, git-clone

I cloned an existing git repository to my new PC.But after cloning i opened the repository folder in Windows explorer.Everything seems fine.But when i opened the same repository in eclipse,my library files seems to be missing,eventhough it is there in explorer.I tried restarting eclipse.But that didn't solve my problem.Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your libraries to eclipse workspace one by one. When importing make sure that checkbox "Copy projects into workspace" is NOT checked.

Comment: Ok.I'll try this.Whenever i sync my workspace and the remote repository,the library projects which i added gets invisible in eclipse.Its there in file explorer,but not in Eclipse.